# with jquery UI dialog, is there anyway to have a max height and use 'auto' if its smaller

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I want a dialog to have a max height setting but, if the content is smaller, then to shrink down to do what `height = 'auto'` does. Is this possible in JQuery UI dialog?

Comment: Have you tried CSS `max-height` setting on the class of your dialog? So it will size itself as needed but not over maximum allowed height.

Comment: What is the content?, a div, a page...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing the following:

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
    Dialog content
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    resizable: false,
    minHeight: 0,
    create: function() {
        $(this).css("maxHeight", 400);        
    }
});
```

Check out [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UhGNW/).

Comment: Is there any reason or rationale as to why you would want to specify the max height in the create event as opposed to after the fact like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17218922/469643? Or just preference? Thanks Marcus

Comment: @veeTrain Both works, but I think using the `create` callback is cleaner and easier to read. So, I guess it's preference :)

Answer (score 17):

I use this:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    maxHeight: $(window).height(),
    open: function() {
        $(this).dialog('option', 'maxHeight', $(window).height());
   }
});
```

Resetting maxHeight in "open" is useful when window has changed size.

Comment: Works for me, but with a slight change: I added 'px' to the maxHeight option.
$(this).dialog('option', 'maxHeight', $(window).height() + 'px');

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
 $('#testing').resizable("enable");
 $('#testing').dialog({ maxHeight: 400 });


<div id="testing" class="ui-widget-content">
<h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: @ooo you can combine resizing with maxHeight. You can refer to this site http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137849/Dialog

Comment: but i don't want to allow the person to resize it after that

Comment: The maxHeight only applies to the resizable max hieght not the initial opening max height. http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-maxHeight   "The maximum height to which the dialog can be resized, in pixels."

Answer (score 2):

After dialog `.open()`, and filling with `.html()`:

```
$("#div").css('max-height','500px');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could work together with `height`and `maxHeight` and fit the dialog height when your div content height < dialog maxheight. Do this when the dialog is `open`. Like this:

```
<div id="dialog">
  <div id="contents">
    <input type="text" style="height:3000px"
  </div>  
</div>


    $('#dialog').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      maxHeight:400,
      height:400,
      buttons: {
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    open:function(){
       var s = $('#contents').height();
       var s2 = $(this).dialog( "option", "maxHeight" );
       if(s < s2){
         $(this).height(s);
       }
    }
});
```

try it changing the `style="height:3000px`value: 
http://jsbin.com/iwecuf/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

[Bug #4820](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4820) in jQuery UI Dialog is applicable, and you may be interested in the workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Let me throw my 2 cents in.

Create a CSS Style like so

```
.d-maxheight {  max-height:200px; }
```

Now simply tell the dialog to apply that class to the dialog

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(d).dialog({
    dialogClass: 'd-maxheight',
    height:400
  });
});
```

[Here is an example in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iloder/3/edit)

As long as you content is less than the max height it will automatically size. If not the max height will take effect and you will get a scroll bar inside the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the dialog contents in another div that has max-height applied, like this:

```
<div id="dialog">
  <div style="max-height: 400px;">
      POPUP CONTENTS GO HERE
  </div>
</div>
```