# Setting max height of a dialog, then allow scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I can't seem to understand how to set the height correctly for the jquery ui dialog.

I want it to display the height to however much content is present, but if it exceeds 400 pixels, then I want a scroll bar.

So, if the content has 200 pixels in height, then the dialog should have a height of 200 pixels.

If the content has a height larger than 400 pixels, then the dialog shouldn't expand past 400 pixels and a scroll bar should be visible.

I have this so far:

```
$("#popup").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false

});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("#popup").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false
});
```

css

```
#popup {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 4px;
 padding: 10px;
 overflow: auto;
 max-height: 300px;   
}​
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JNKPB/1/)

**Edit** Updated fiddle and adjusted code so it would work. Not sure why, by the jQuery UI dialog `maxHeight` doesn't seem to be doing what it should. I just added the max height part to the CSS and all was fine and dandy.

Comment: I tried setting maxHeight, but it doesn't seem to work.  The dialog is still very tall, it didn't do anything actually (i cleard the browser cache also, in firefox/chrome/ie).

Comment: Can you add some example code of what is being loaded into the dialog? Maybe post a jsfiddle? I got you started. http://jsfiddle.net/JNKPB/

Comment: The css styles/images aren't working on fiddle, anyhow, I have 1 or more rows of this: `<div class="dialog-item">
 <form name="form1">
  Here is some text for the dialog, hello world!
  <div class="dialog-item-inputs">
   <a href="#">Click here</a>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
`

Comment: So the solution is based on CSS and not the dialog attribute right?

Comment: Yes, I took the `maxHeight` out of the `.dialog()` all together as it certainly wasn't stopping it from getting bigger.

Comment: also see this for doing it in the initialiser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661913/with-jquery-ui-dialog-is-there-anyway-to-have-a-max-height-and-use-auto-if-it

Comment: In order to specify a runtime max-height for your dialog/pop-up, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17218922/469643; similar to  the solutions at @Flapper 's link