# Jquery mobile dialog scrollable

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile for my app, I used `data-native-menu="false"` on a select.

```
<select id="chosenpro" data-theme="a" data-native-menu="false">
</select>
```

Jquery Mobile opens a <strike>dialog</strike> popup with this classes :

```
.ui-popup-container .ui-popup-active
```

Then I styled the `<li>`s inside it to make them look like a grid with `display:inline-block;` including images. 
But I would like this popup to be scrollable, because it is higher than my page.

I am aware of this answer, but not able to adapt it to my case :
[Setting max height of a dialog, then allow scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193455/setting-max-height-of-a-dialog-then-allow-scrolling)

Can you help please ?

http://jsfiddle.net/LzLEw/6/

Thanks

Comment: Now it different! working on it.

Comment: I guess it's better to create a new popup dynamically rather than modifying the one jQM creates. It requires some time to test it thoroughly. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LzLEw/7/ this is how it should look.

Comment: I'd better use the jqm popup if possible, and just make it scrolable on phones. (if possible)

Answer (score 2):

`select` menu with `data-menu-native="false"` are converted into either *popup* or *dialog* depending on screen's height and number of options.

The *popup*/_dialog_ holds `id` of the `select` menu plus `-dialog`. E.g. If `select` menu's `id` is `foo`, the *dialog*'s `id` becomes `foo-dialog`.

To manipulate that *dialog*, you need first to retrieve its' `id` and then bind any *page event* to do any changes.

The best event to do such modifications is `pageinit` as it fires only one time per *page*. After retrieving `select` menu's `id`, bind `pageinit` to that *dialog* to make changes on `data-role=content` containing `select` menu's *options*.

The changes you need to apply to `data-role=content` are, `height` and <strike>`overflow-y`</strike>.

> **Update:** You don't need to override `overflow-y`, setting a fixed `height` is enough.

```
/* when pageX which contains long selectmenu
   is being initialized, retrieve selectmenu's id */

$(document).on("pageinit", "#pageID", function () {

    /* selectmenu's id */
    var selectID = "#" + $("select", this)[0].id + "-dialog";

    /* dialog is being initialized,
       change height to half screen's height */
    $(document).on("pageinit", selectID, function () {
        var height = $.mobile.getScreenHeight() / 2;
        $(".ui-content", this).css({
            height: height
        });
    });
});
```

> **[Demo - jQM 1.3.2](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LzLEw/)** <sup>(1)</sup>

<sup>(1)</sup> Tested on iPhone 5 - Safari Mobile

Comment: Hi @Omar, I edited my question and the comments disappeared...sorry I didn't know this. And yes you were right it is a popup not a dialog

Comment: I am sorry! SO newbie mistake. Should I avoid editing my question to avoid removing comments ? Would it help if I edited your answer (not sure so...) ?

Comment: @Louis you can edit your question with any comment. I dont know how your comments were removed. I've removed my comments on your question.

Comment: I modified your jsfiddle to better represent the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/LzLEw/6/    when the viewport is reduced (on a phone) I need the popup to be scrollable.

Comment: Hint : if I use this css : `#chosenpro-menu {
 height: 200px !important;
 overflow-y:scroll;
}` it makes it scrollable on my desktop browser but not on my android browser.

Comment: @Louis `overflow-y: scroll;` doesn't work on Android as far as I know., or they look buggy.

Comment: ok that's bad news...  I was wondering then if I could force a `dialog` instead of a `popup` but I see that "Dialogs are deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0"...  Maybe I should upgrade to jquery 1.4 and see how's the popup then ?

Comment: I see that it's the `display:inline-block;` in my css that makes it a popup instead of a dialog....maybe I can circumvent this and make it a dialog again...so at leat it'll be scrollable...

Comment: @Louis I'll test it on jQM 1.4. I dont know what panels jQM is going to have for custom selectmenus. What I'm working on now, is create a custom selectmenu (popup) from the scratch.